Convert table to reflect column names as row values
I have brand rankings (row values) by customer in the following table:



CustID
Brand1
Brand2
Brand3
Brand4
Brand5
Brand6
Brand10




1
3
1
2

5

4


2

2
1

4
3
5


3
2
3

4

1
5



I would like to transform this table to represent rankings as columns and brands as rows:



CustID
1
2
3
4
5




1
Brand2
Brand3
Brand1
Brand10
Brand5


2
Brand3
Brand2
Brand6
Brand5
Brand10


3
Brand6
Brand1
Brand2
Brand4
Brand10



I have 116 customers in total, 10 Brands and Rankings 1 to 5. I tried unpivoting and pivoting tables but values in pivot tables show counts, not Brand names.
How can I transform my table?

It's fairly simple with Power Pivot:

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    UnpivotedData = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"CustID"}, "Brand", "Rank"),
    FilteredData = Table.SelectRows(UnpivotedData, each [Rank] <> null),
    ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(FilteredData,{{"Rank", type text}}),
    PivotedData = Table.Pivot(ChangeType, List.Distinct(ChangeType[Rank]), "Rank", "Brand"),
    SortedColumnNames = List.Sort(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(PivotedData), 1), (x) => Number.FromText(x)),
    SortedColumns = Table.ReorderColumns(PivotedData, List.Combine({{"CustID"}, SortedColumnNames}))
in
    SortedColumns


While you have already got a solution using Power Query here are few methods using Excel Formulas:


• Formula used in cell A6
=LET(
     _Data, Ranktbl[#All],
     _Rank, DROP(_Data,1,1),
     _RankN, SORT(UNIQUE(TOROW(_Rank,1),1),,,1),
     _Output, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_Data)-1,COLUMNS(_RankN),LAMBDA(r,c,
     INDEX(TOCOL(IF(INDEX(_RankN,c)=_Rank,
     DROP(TAKE(_Data,1),,1),NA()),2),r,))),
     HSTACK(TAKE(_Data,,1),VSTACK(_RankN,_Output)))


Also, if applicable can use PIVOTBY() function:
=LET(
     _Data, Ranktbl[#All],
     _Fx, LAMBDA(α,δ, TOCOL(IF(α<>"",δ,NA()),2)),
     _Rank, DROP(_Data,1,1),
     PIVOTBY(_Fx(_Rank,DROP(TAKE(_Data,,1),1)),
             _Fx(_Rank,_Rank),
             _Fx(_Rank,DROP(TAKE(_Data,1),,1)),
             SINGLE,,0,,0))


Or, To write each steps making it easier to read:
=LET(
     _Data, Ranktbl[#All],
     _Fx, LAMBDA(α,δ, TOCOL(IF(α<>"",δ,NA()),2)),
     _Rank, DROP(_Data,1,1),
     _Customer, _Fx(_Rank,DROP(TAKE(_Data,,1),1)),
     _Brand, _Fx(_Rank,DROP(TAKE(_Data,1),,1)),
     _RankN, _Fx(_Rank,_Rank),
     PIVOTBY(_Customer,_RankN,_Brand,SINGLE,,0,,0))



Thank you, however Let didn't work with my formulas ((

@BT what do you mean by not working. All given formulas are applied on Excel and its definitely working. When you say not working should be posting relevant screenshots to validate your justification otherwise it becomes no sense!

Sorry for being so vague
I am unable to post a screenshot here, but here is the error I get on popup window - "The first argument of LET must be a valid name"

@BT bro this is not an issue at all, the reason you get, possibly you have any defined names or sheet names as _Data just change the variables within LET() as per your preference. The formula should work!

Will do, thank you! So, _Data is the sheet name in your formula?

@BT do you have any defined names or sheet names as any of those defined variables within the LET()? No, I am asking you the question, I dont know what defined names or sheet names you have

Another formula option, based on your sample data and description, if the number of rankings per row is always 5 (no more; no less):
=LET(
    tbl; Table1[#All];
    rank; DROP(tbl; 1; 1);
    test; ISNUMBER(rank);
    unpivot; SORTBY(
        TOCOL(IFS(test; DROP(TAKE(tbl; 1);; 1)); 2);
        TOCOL(IFS(test; SEQUENCE(ROWS(rank))); 2); 1;
        TOCOL(IFS(test; rank); 2); 1);
    HSTACK(TAKE(tbl;; 1); VSTACK(SEQUENCE(1; 5); WRAPROWS(unpivot; 5)))
)

If the number of rankings per row is not fixed, however, use the following modified version:
=LET(
    tbl; Table1[#All];
    rank; DROP(tbl; 1; 1);
    n; COLUMNS(rank);
    cols; SEQUENCE(; n);
    test; ISNUMBER(rank);
    unpivot; SORTBY(
        TOCOL(IF(test; DROP(TAKE(tbl; 1);; 1); ""));
        TOCOL(IF(cols; SEQUENCE(ROWS(rank)))); 1;
        TOCOL(IF(test; rank)); 1);
    pivot; HSTACK(TAKE(DROP(tbl; 1);; 1); WRAPROWS(unpivot; n));
    FILTER(VSTACK(HSTACK("CustID"; cols); pivot); BYCOL(pivot; LAMBDA(col; SUM(LEN(col)))))
)

Adjust the tbl definition, if necessary, but be sure to include the header row of your table or range.
Note: I used semi-colon separators in the formulas above, because of your discussion in the comments... "The first argument of LET must be a valid name" error can occur when copying/pasting formulas found online, if the author uses a different system separator than you. If your default separator is not a semi-colon, paste the formulas into Notepad first and use Edit > Replace... to replace the semi-colons with commas, for example (or vice-versa).
